# Discord Music bot VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

I wanted to programm my own discord bot, which plays some songs from youtube but it wont create the ydl player this is the error `Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'` and this is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def s(ctx):
    user=ctx.message.author
    voicech = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = await  voicech.connect()
    player = await voice.create_ytdl_player("some url")

    
    
    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player()
    player.start()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`create_ytdl_player` was the old way of creating a player. With [discord.py@rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (> v.1.0), playing music is a bit more complicated. There are two ways to play music. For both ways, using FFmpeg will be necessary, so you'll have to [install it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_KqycyErd8).

Here are two of ways to play videos (with `youtube-dl` and `ffmpeg`):

- From file (you'll have to download files):

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

@bot.command(brief="Plays a single video, from a youtube URL") #or bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    YDL_OPTIONS = {
        'format': 'bestaudio',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
        'outtmpl': 'song.%(ext)s',
    }

    with YoutubeDL(Music.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        ydl.download("URL", download=True)

    if not voice.is_playing():
        voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
        voice.is_playing()
        await ctx.send(f"Now playing {url}")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Already playing song")
        return
```

- Without downloading music. This is simpler to play music this way, however, this causes a know issue, [well explained here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035010351--Known-Issue-Music-Bots-Not-Playing-Music-From-Certain-Sources) so you'll have to add a `FFMPEG_OPTIONS` variable:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

@bot.command(brief="Plays a single video, from a youtube URL")
async def play(ctx, url):
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if not voice.is_playing():
        with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(video_link, download=False)
        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
        voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        voice.is_playing()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Already playing song")
        return
```

These commands will only play songs so you'll have to program every other commands (join, leave, ...).
There are a lot of example on internet, you should look at them once you're used to creating music bots.

**Reference:**  [`VoiceClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice#discord.VoiceClient) documentation.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this but now i get the following error`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found`.

Comment: @Mat Use `@client.command(brief="Plays a single video, from a youtube URL")` instead of `@commands.command(brief="Plays a single video, from a youtube URL")`. Note that you no longer need to write `pass_context=True` in `discord.py-rewrite`.

Comment: Im sorry for interrupting you again now im getting this error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'get' is not defined`

Comment: You need to write `from discord.utils import get` ^^ My bad, this is a part of my code and I forgot to change some things.

Comment: Sorry for another interuption but so Im gettings this error `eError: name 'self' is not defined` im tried to fix by deleting this part and replacing the `self.bot.voice_clients` by `client.voice_clients`then i got this error `name 'youtube_dl' is not defined`. YTDL is installed.

Comment: And what is with the ytdl Thing?

Comment: I know Im using it alot but Im getting this error even if its installed.

Comment: Yup, I didn't realised that I wrote `with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:`. I directly imported `YoutubeDL` so it wasn't recognising `youtube_dl`. You just have to replace the line to `with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:`

Comment: Now its working thank you a lot is there way to stop it?

Comment: You simply have to create a new command, `stop` for instance, and write `voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)` and `voice.stop()` (you'll have to do some error managment too). [`VoiceClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice#discord.VoiceClient) documentation.

Comment: I suggest changing `URL = info['formats'][0]['url']` to `URL = info['url']` so you actually use the format set by `YDL_OPTIONS`