# Discord.py Bot How to play audio from local files

Tags: python, audio, bots, discord.py

Basically the title. I installed ffmpeg and discord.py[audio] already. I just need to learn how it works. couldn't find any tutorial for local audio files. and I cant understand anything from documentations :/

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.FFmpegPCMAudio https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.play What have you tried so far? What are the error messages you are receiving?

Comment: im new to these stuffs and I legit can't connect the informations from docs in my mind :/ Like I can see there is a source block and play block but then?? how??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Music bot VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create\_ytdl\_player'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024148/discord-music-bot-voiceclient-object-has-no-attribute-create-ytdl-player)

Comment: I may be wrong but I guess this question is asking about audio from internet. im trying to play local files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a function that plays a local audio file. I had problems with FFmpeg, so I hardcoded the .exe path. Also, I had a problem with the file path to the local file, so I put the absolute path in. This function also deletes the command that called it after the audio is done playing, keeping things tidy.

```
 @bot.command(name="<command_name>")
    async def <function_name>(ctx):
        # Gets voice channel of message author
        voice_channel = ctx.author.channel
        channel = None
        if voice_channel != None:
            channel = voice_channel.name
            vc = await voice_channel.connect()
            vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source="C:<path_to_file>"))
            # Sleep while audio is playing.
            while vc.is_playing():
                sleep(.1)
            await vc.disconnect()
        else:
            await ctx.send(str(ctx.author.name) + "is not in a channel.")
        # Delete command after the audio is done playing.
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: it worked perfectly. thank you. also I want to note here something real quick. if you guys getting error like `'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`... place `r` before path strings like this: `...source = r"C:\Users..."` or use `/` instead of "\"