# Play Local Audio File Discord.py

Tags: python, audio, bots, discord.py

Saw this question asked in a similar post linked here: [Discord.py Bot How to play audio from local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036753/discord-py-bot-how-to-play-audio-from-local-files)

I slightly tweaked this but I keep getting "Unused variable 'channel'.
Here's my code.

```
async def test(ctx):
    voice_channel = ctx.author.channel
    channel = None
    if voice_channel != None:
        channel = voice_channel.name
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="D:/FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe", source="<file directory goes here>"))
        while vc.is_playing():
            time.sleep(.1)
        await vc.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send(str(ctx.author.name) + "is not in a channel.")
```

Comment: use `await asyncio.sleep()` instead of `time.sleep`, it blocks your whole code, you won't be able to do anything else when you're playing music.

Answer (score 0):

The alert you're getting is probably because you never use the channel variable. If you want to remove the alert, do something like

```py
async def test(ctx):
    voice_channel = ctx.author.channel
    channel = None
    if voice_channel != None:
        channel = voice_channel.name
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="D:/FFMPEG/ffmpeg.exe", source="<file directory goes here>"))
        await ctx.send("Connected to " + channel)
        while vc.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(.1)
        await vc.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send(str(ctx.author.name) + "is not in a channel.")
```

Also use asyncio, as noted by Łukasz Kwieciński. You can also just comment that line out as it's useless in your current code