# potato quality audio coming from bot

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord.py

When I play audio through my bot it sounds really bad, I have a fast internet connection, so what could be causing this? Im running my bot on a Raspberry Pi 3. Im using FFMpeg. Could the RPI be bottlenecking it somehow. Is it my code?

simplified version of my code:

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(ctx.message.author.voice.channel.id)
    voice = await channel.connect()
    if not voice.is_playing():
        voice.play(await discord.FFMpegOpusAudio(source='/path/to/file'))
        while voice.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    discord.AudioSource.cleanup(str(ctx.message.author.voice.channel.id))
```

Comment: Where do you download your videos?

Comment: I download the videos from youtube using a libary called pafy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `pafy` documentation, you'd have to do this:

```py
def download_song(url)
    video = pafy.new(url)
    best = video.getbest()
    best.download(quiet=False)
```

However, I recommend using:

- `youtube-dl`:

  ```
  pip install youtube-dl
  ```

  ```py
  from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

  ydl_opts = {
      'format': 'bestaudio/best',
      'noplaylist':'True',
      'outtmpl': 'song.%(ext)s'
      'postprocessors': [{
          'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
          'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
          'preferredquality': '192',
      }],
  }

  def download_song(arg, url=True):
      with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
          query = f"ytsearch:{arg}" if url else arg
          data = ydl.extract_info(query, download=True)
      return data if url else data['entries'][0]

  def display_info(data):
      video_info = {
          'title': data['title']
          'duration': data['duration']
          'uploader': data['uploader']
          'thumbnail': data['thumbnail']
          'url': data['webpage_url']
          'channel': data['channel_url']
      }
      for key, val in video_info.items():
          print(f"{key}: {val}")
  ```

  This function will allow you to download songs from urls and queries (eg. "30 sec video"). `youtube_dl` offers [a lot of options](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md).
- [`Wavelink`](https://github.com/PythonistaGuild/Wavelink) (lavalink wrapper for discord.py → better audio and audio control):

  ```
  pip install lavalink
  ```

  ```py
  #Wavelink github example
  import discord
  import wavelink
  from discord.ext import commands


  class Bot(commands.Bot):

      def __init__(self):
          super(Bot, self).__init__(command_prefix=['audio ', 'wave ','aw '])

          self.add_cog(Music(self))

      async def on_ready(self):
          print(f'Logged in as {self.user.name} | {self.user.id}')


  class Music(commands.Cog):

      def __init__(self, bot):
          self.bot = bot

          if not hasattr(bot, 'wavelink'):
              self.bot.wavelink = wavelink.Client(bot=self.bot)

          self.bot.loop.create_task(self.start_nodes())

      async def start_nodes(self):
          await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

          # Initiate our nodes. For this example we will use one server.
          # Region should be a discord.py guild.region e.g sydney or us_central (Though this is not technically required)
          await self.bot.wavelink.initiate_node(host='127.0.0.1',
                                                port=2333,
                                                rest_uri='http://127.0.0.1:2333',
                                                password='youshallnotpass',
                                                identifier='TEST',
                                                region='us_central')

      @commands.command(name='connect')
      async def connect_(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=None):
          if not channel:
              try:
                  channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
              except AttributeError:
                  raise discord.DiscordException('No channel to join. Please either specify a valid channel or join one.')

          player = self.bot.wavelink.get_player(ctx.guild.id)
          await ctx.send(f'Connecting to **`{channel.name}`**')
          await player.connect(channel.id)

      @commands.command()
      async def play(self, ctx, *, query: str):
          tracks = await self.bot.wavelink.get_tracks(f'ytsearch:{query}')

          if not tracks:
              return await ctx.send('Could not find any songs with that query.')

          player = self.bot.wavelink.get_player(ctx.guild.id)
          if not player.is_connected:
              await ctx.invoke(self.connect_)

          await ctx.send(f'Added {str(tracks[0])} to the queue.')
          await player.play(tracks[0])


  bot = Bot()
  bot.run('TOKEN')
  ```

  This one is more complex but will let you have more controll over your music player. Personally, I think that `youtube-dl` is sufficient for playing audio in discord but it's up to you.

Comment: Okay, I'll try ytdl first and see if it satisfies me.

Comment: ok so ytdl downloads the song but looking at the code, instead of downloading it in mp3 format it does it in webm format. sorry if im wrong, i haven't used this library before so i have no idea how it works. also it's clipping a whole bunch.

Comment: Should output as mp3 now. I play audio without downloading it so I've never tried to download videos ^^

Comment: oh, you can do that?

Comment: I wrote a pretty complete answer about [playing audio with youtube-dl and ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024148/discord-music-bot-voiceclient-object-has-no-attribute-create-ytdl-player/63029039#63029039), there are both ways in it.