# Making the bot create a ytdl to play music

Tags: discord.py

So I am trying to do a music bot except it is not playing the audio. Here is the error I got:

`'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'`

I know already I have to do the following:

```
author = ctx.message.author
channel = author.voice_channel
await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

But the thing is it also gives and error. So I have come up with the following code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect()
    
    await ctx.send("**Playing** Lofi music")
    player = await voice.create_ytdl_player("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FlxM_0S2lA&ab_channel=ChilledCow")
    players[server.id] = player
    player.start()
```

But again, it came up with the error above. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a duplicate: [Discord Music bot VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024148/discord-music-bot-voiceclient-object-has-no-attribute-create-ytdl-player/63029039#63029039)
But [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) has been taken down and is no longer accessible for plublic. So I'll add some more informations.

---

## EDIT

`youtube_dl` re-opened for public so the [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024148/discord-music-bot-voiceclient-object-has-no-attribute-create-ytdl-player/63029039#63029039) works again.

---

If you still don't want to use `youtube_dl`:

You'll have to use libraries like [`pafy`](https://pypi.org/project/pafy/), which has still access to `youtube-dl`. Here's a short example:

```py
from pafy import new
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx):
    ffmpeg_opts = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect()
        
    await ctx.send("**Playing** Lofi music")
    video = new("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FlxM_0S2lA&ab_channel=ChilledCow")
    audio = video.getbestaudio().url
    voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(audio, **ffmpeg_opts))
    voice.is_playing()
```

More informations here:

- For the code to work, you'll need to [install ffmpeg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_KqycyErd8).
- `ffmpeg_opts` solves a known issue explained [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035010351--Known-Issue-Music-Bots-Not-Playing-Music-From-Certain-Sources).
- If you want more informations about `pafy`, here's the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pafy/)

Comment: FFmpegPCMAudio is not defined! I checked if I was right and it is not defined! Could you explain how to use it?

Comment: I forgot to import `FFmpegPCMAudio`, should work now