# 'VoiceClient' object is not callable with discord API/youtube_dl

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm making a music bot using youtube_dl and discord.py. I am running into a problem making a "play" command and I can't seem to resolve it. I have the join and leave command both working, the bot joins but when I type .play[url] it shows the error below.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
   guild = ctx.message.guild
   voice_client = guild.voice_client(guild)
   player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
   players[server.id] = player
   player.start()
```

Error: `voice_client = guild.voice_client(guild) TypeError: 'VoiceClient' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[voice_client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.voice_client) is a field so you can just write
`voice_client = guild.voice_client` without the parentheses.

Comment: That seemed to have worked, thank you. But now I get this error: `'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'`.

Comment: It looks like changes were made to the `VoiceClient` object, it may be worth looking into [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024148/discord-music-bot-voiceclient-object-has-no-attribute-create-ytdl-player) @Jure