# No audio from discord bot. discord.py/ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

I'm creating a simple music bot and I cant figure out why there is no audio from the bot. I've tried kicking and rejoining, changing code and more. I just cant figure this out. There is no errors from the command line and the bot has a little green circle around it as if there was audio from it. However it goes away if you rejoin the VC.

Here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient

import youtube_dl
import os

TOKEN = "Token Here"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='s')
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels(), id=794444804607574026)
    await channel.connect()
    
    
@bot.command(name='play')
async def play(ctx, url):
    await message.content.startswith('play')
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player = await voice.create_ytdl_player("https://youtu.be/K4DyBUG242c")
    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player()
    player.start()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

If you want to, feel free to improve it. I got this code from a YouTube tutorial so I don't completely understand the audio part.

Comment: What does this line `await message.content.startswith('play')` even mean? Firstly you didn't define `message` and secondly why are you awaiting it?

Comment: You're using outdated methods. If you watch tutorials, please watch recent ones since `discord.py` is frequently updated. For intance, you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024148/discord-music-bot-voiceclient-object-has-no-attribute-create-ytdl-player/63029039#63029039)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. When you run the command the message will never start with `play`, the bot prefix is `","`.

Also, you add `intents` to `client`. You should set it to `bot` instead and delete `client`, you never use it in the code.

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient

import youtube_dl
import os

TOKEN = "Token Here"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels(), id=794444804607574026)
    await channel.connect()
    
    
@bot.command(name='play')
async def play(ctx, url):
    # await message.content.startswith('play')
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player = await voice.create_ytdl_player("https://youtu.be/K4DyBUG242c")
    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player()
    player.start()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: it just gave me this big error: 
 File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: url is a required argument that is missing.
@FoxGames01

Comment: Really i dont know. If you copied that code from a YouTube video and it didn't work, you probably have seen a video from an outdated version of discord.py. Whenever you go to watch a programming youtube tutorial, remember to see the version in which the code was written.