# Discord music bot error "AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'play'"

Tags: python, discord

I'm having trouble with this.

So this is part of my code (the URL scrapping works fine)

```
if(ctx.author.voice):
 channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
 await ctx.send("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+search_results[0])  
 url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+search_results[0]
 await channel.connect()
 channel.play(discord.FFmpegAudio(url))
else:
 await ctx.send("Necesitas estar en un canal de audio para usar este comando")
```

this is the error I am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'play'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`play` is a method of the `VoiceClient` object returned by `await channel.connect()`, not the channel itself, so your code should be:

```py
conn = await channel.connect()
conn.play(discord.FFmpegAudio(url))
```

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that FFmpegAudio doesn't accept a youtube video link, so you'll need to download it with youtube-dl or something similar. (maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024148/discord-music-bot-voiceclient-object-has-no-attribute-create-ytdl-player ?)